# Proving an equivalence relation on subsets of integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and define a relation $\tau$ on the power set of $X$ as follows: $\forall A, B \in P(X)$,
$A \tau B$ if and only if the sum of the elements in $A$ equals the sum of the elements in $B$.

(a) Prove that $\tau$ is an equivalence relation.

(b) Let $X = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. Write down the partition of $P(X)$ given by the equivalence classes of
$\tau$ for this set $X$.

Comment: Any idea ??????

Comment: Just not idea about power set

Comment: Maybe it helps to start with listing the lements of $\mathcal P(X)$. $X$ has $4$ elements; thus, its power set has $2^4=16$ elements, starting from $\emptyset$ and ending with $X$ itself.

Comment: Start reviewing the def of [Power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set).

Comment: The equiv classes will be defined by the possible value of the sum of elements of subsets of $A$. We will have $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ as possible values. Thus, we may imagine that we will have $7$ equiv classes. For example, the two subsets $\{ 1, 2 \}$ and $\{ 3 \}$ will be in the same equiv class, because they are related by $\tau$.

Comment: The equiv class having $6$ has sum of elements will be $\{ \{ 1,2,3 \}, \{ 0,1,2,3 \} \}$.

Comment: The equiv class having $5$ has sum of elements will be $\{ \{ 0,2,3 \},\{ 2,3 \} \}$.

Comment: The equiv class having $4$ has sum of elements will be $\{ \{ 0,1,3 \}, \{ 1,3 \} \}$.

Comment: The equiv class having $3$ has sum of elements will be $\{ \{ 0,1,2 \}, \{ 1,2 \}, \{ 0, 3 \}, \{ 3 \} \}$.

Comment: The equiv class having $2$ has sum of elements will be $\{ \{ 0,2 \}, \{ 2 \} \}$.

Comment: The equiv class having $1$ has sum of elements will be $\{ \{ 0,1 \}, \{ 1 \} \}$.

Comment: The equiv class having $0$ has sum of elements will be ????